# Why can I not assign publicip.get() to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ip

**Update**

If I do `print(publicip.get())` then I get the correct ip addressed printed.

If I do `myip = publicip.get()` and then do `print(myip)`, then the value `None` gets printed

**Original Question**

When I ran the site on localhost, the value of `myip` would be 127.0.0.1. But `publicip.get()` would give me my public IP address. Unfortunately if `myip = "127.0.0.1"`: and `if myip = 127.0.0.1:` give me syntax errors. What is the correct way of checking the value in the variable `myip`.

```
     myip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
     if myip = "127.0.0.1":
        myip = publicip.get()

     print("myip")
     print(myip)
```

Answer (score 2):

`=` is an assignment operator, while equality can be checked with `==`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why ip = publicip.get() would not be working? 

print(publicip.get()) prints out my correct IP address. But when I do  ip = publicip.get(), then ip equals None.

Comment: What kind of object is `publicip`?

Comment: How would I determine what sort of object it is?

Comment: Okay, seems like publicip is a package. Its function `get()` seems to just print the IP address, not return it. It would be difficult to grab it out there.

Comment: That is frustrating. Thank you for having a look.

Comment: But it might be even unnecessary to get the own "public" IP address. Most network software does not need this information to work. Therefore it would be good to know what you want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219565/discussion-between-ross-symonds-and-heap-underflow).